# Computing max of 2, length n bit registries

Tags: quantum-algorithms

Define a quantum algorithm that computes the maximum of two n-qubit registers.

> From Quantum Computing: A Gentle Introduction (Eleanor Rieffle & Wolfgang Polak), exercise 6.4.a (page 121).

I know how to do this classically using bit logic and a signed bit, but I don’t think there are signed bits in quantum computing. I think the answer should be pretty straight forward but I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will not give you the exact answer but here are some hints:

- You already know how to perform the addition (mod $2^n$) of 2 $n$-qubit quantum registers (section 6.4.3).
- Let's say you want to compare $a$ and $b$ stored in binary in registers, **if the most significant bit of $a$ is 0**, then the most significant bit of $a-b (\text{mod} \ 2^n)$ is $1$ if and only if $a < b$ (the subtraction is done with unsigned integer, the result should be interpreted as a unsigned integer in the previous sentence).
- Exercise 6.4.b statement *may* help you understand. For those who do not have the book:

  > **Exercise 6.4.b:** Explain why such an algorithm requires one additional qubit that cannot be reused; that is, the algorithm will have to have $2n+1$ input and output qubits.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution I can think of is use a comparator circuit. If $a<b$, this will output 1 in another qubit register. You can then put $b$ in another register using Toffolis with this qubit as control if you want the result in another register.